# How to change font size and tab width & height of jQuery-UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery-UI to add [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) on my page, after I added it, I feel the tab font size and tab width and height are too large for my page. I would like to change the font size and tab width and height. How to do it?

Comment: That manual page says "The jQuery UI Tabs plugin uses the jQuery UI CSS Framework to style its look and feel, including colors and background textures. We recommend using the ThemeRoller tool to create and download custom themes that are easy to build and maintain.". I'd look into that.

Comment: Have a look here http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html

Comment: Have any of these answers worked for you? If so, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 26):

you need to change it in a css class like this

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {font-size:7pt !important;}
```

Comment: But if you have 2 or more tab widgets in your page it would affect all of 'em.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and create your own theme or modify the presets. On the right hand side under 'Font settings' there is the option to change the font size.

[image: ThemeRoller Font Settings]

As for the size of the tabs, look at the CSS file that came with the jQuery UI package you downloaded. Find the selector for the jQuery UI tabs and edit the padding property:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: left; padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox 84.0 (Jan 2021) this worked:

```js
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  color: blue !important;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  color: blue !important;
  // etc.
}
```

Note that I needed both of those specifications; i.e.: set `color` in both `li a {}` and `a {}`.